# JQuery Syntax Check -- Array Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

```
var selections = [];

$dragContainerDiv1.on("click", ".draggable1", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $this = $(event.target);
    if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
        $this.removeClass("selected");
        selections.splice(selections.indexOf($this), 1);
    }
    else {
        selections.push($this);
        $this.addClass("selected");
        initDraggable($this);
    }
});
```

My arrays don't seem stable and I'm thinking it's because my jQuery syntax is not right. The click event is occurring on a list of div tags which contain text, data-id, and data-text. The idea is to be able to multi-select the draggable divs.

So, when initially clicked, it adds the div to the array and highlights it. When clicked again, it removes the div from the array. Eventually, the group of selected divs are dragged to the drop zone, where I recover the data and post it to the server.

If I click rapidly through multiple divs, it appears that the selected divs are not always the ones in the array.

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle which shows your problem?

Comment: What does this do: `initDraggable($this);`?

Comment: I don't think `selections.indexOf($this)` will ever work, since you are creating a new object each time and the references won't be the same. Is there a reason you need the `selections` array at all? Why not select `$('.draggable1.selected')` when it's time to send data to the server?

Comment: initDraggable() calls jQuery UI draggable

Comment: Jason, I've been thinking the array might have been a bad idea and I should try something with the classes. That was going to be my next step if this doesn't work out.

Comment: Now I remember why I did it this way. I need to have a way to group the divs for dragging. That's how the array got introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your removing of $this from your selections array isn't working.  selections.indexOf($this) is always returning -1, and therefore your selections.splice(-1, 1) is removing the last element from selections. What you want to store in selections is the element contained in the $this object:

```
selections.push($this[0]);
```

And when removing:

```
selections.splice(selections.indexOf($this[0]), 1);
```